# How can we avoid error block executing even if client side error are occured in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

What i mean is ,if we hit an url and try to cancel it ,the error block is executed .But what I am trying is to do is avoiding  coming into error block when client side error occurs and executing error block only when there is an error from server side in angular js

Comment: How exactly are you cancelling the action?

Comment: forming a object with method,url,timeout.and making a request as http(object)

Comment: And how do you cancel the request?

Comment: Yes but i just want to know how it is cancelled either by server or client.just i want to have alert msg if there is error due to server error and print if the error is from client side

Comment: My question is *how* are you cancelling the request?

Comment: i have commented it .By sending timeout directly into a object and passing it to http..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87485/discussion-between-naga-bhavani-and-ed-hinchliffe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of the question - you're trying to ensure you don't execute error code if the request times out, only executing it when the server returns an error.

The best way to do this is to inspect the `status` property of the error argument that is passed to the catch block, **for a timeout, the status will be 0**:

```
  var req={ 
    method : 'GET', 
    url :"url",
    cache:'templateCache', 
    timeout: 100 
  };

  $http(req)

  .then( function () {
    // Success case
    console.log("success");
  })

  .catch( function (e){
    // This happens if the request is cancelled
    if(e.status === 0)
      console.warn("Request timed out");
      return;

    // Handle server errors here.
    console.error("Server error", e);

  });
```